# Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, perl-module

I have 3 arrays and then I open a txt file which contains firstname , lastname and email(alone with some html codes like shown below)

```
<first>Mike<first>
<sec>stone<sec>
<email>mike@rt.com<email>
```

I first count the lines in the file, then I parse this file and put first , last and email in 3 different arrays and then I remove the htmls tags from each array element. But I'm facing problems like Global symbol required explicit package name  in one of the variable during removing the html tags even if I have declared it with my
Here is the snippet

```
    if ( $ct <= $end ) {
        my $i = 0;
    }
    $ct++;
}

my $j = 0;
my $l = @lines;

while ( $j < $l ) {
      if ( $lines[$j] =~ m/@/ ) {
          50 $line[$i] = $lines[$j];

          51 $j = $j - 3;
          52 $last[$i] = $lines[$j];
          53 $j++;
          54 $first[$i] = $lines[$j];
          55 $i++;
          56 $j = $j + 7;
          57;
      }
      else 58 {
          59 $j++;
          60
      }
```

Im getting errors like

```
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at pqwe.pl line 50.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at pqwe.pl line 53.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at pqwe.pl line 55.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at pqwe.pl line 56.
Execution of pqwe.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: If the first `if` is not true then `$i` isn't declared.

Comment: @Biffen, That's not really the problem: `$i` doesn't exists outside of the first `if` block, whether or not it was true.

Comment: It would help reading your code if you didn't include "half-blocks". For instance, the `if` block where `$i` is declared is itself inside a block of an unknown nature because you've cut the beginning out, and your `while` block is also not entirely shown.

Comment: The pseudo-XML doesn't look too good, either. Usually close tags have a slash, like `<sec>First</sec>`. (Also your presupposition that the second name is somebody's family name is problematic.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `$i` declaration out of the `if` block. Check below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var = 1;

if ( $var eq 1)
{
    my $i = 100;
}

print $i."\n";
```

output:

```
# perl test.pl 
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 12.
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Now, I moved the `$i` declaration out of `if` block:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i;
my $var = 1;

if ( $var eq 1)
{
     $i = 100;
}

print $i."\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
# perl test.pl 
100
```

Read More about it in the perl documentation: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Variable-scoping
and http://perlmaven.com/scope-of-variables-in-perl